# Trace method resolution order at runtime

Tags: django, trace

I am working on some code (not mine) and I try to instand it.

There 16 classes in the inheritance tree.

Here area the class according to `inspect.getmro(self.__class__)`

- foo_barcheck.views.barcheck.AdminListActionView
- foo_barcheck.views.barcheck.ListActionMixin
- djangotools.utils.urlresolverutils.UrlMixin
- foo.views.ListActionView
- foo.views.ContextMixin
- foo.views.fooMixin
- djangotools.views.ListActionView
- djangotools.views.ListViewMixin
- django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin
- django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin
- djangotools.views.DTMixin
- django.views.generic.base.TemplateView
- django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin
- django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin
- django.views.generic.base.View
- object

I want to trace what happens if I call `self.do_magic()`.

I want to see all `do_magic()` calls of these 16 classes.

The ideal solution would look like this:

```
result_of_do_magic, list_of_do_magic_methods = trace_method_calls(self.do_magic)
```

I have no clue how to implement `trace_method_calls()`. It should execute the code and trace the method calls at runtime.

Is there a tracing guru which knows how to do this?

AFAIK this needs to be done at runtime, since I don't know if all methods calls the `do_magic()` of the parents via `super()`.

## Update

I don't want to modify the code to be able to trace it. I guess this should be possible, since the mocking library can do comparable magic.

Comment: Please leave a comment why you down-vote this question.

Comment: This is the wrong class hierarchy. `is_valid` is a method on the form, not on the view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman that's what I thought, too. `is_valid()` is for forms. But in the custom code someone wrote a method with the same name. I solved my initial problem, but I am curious, how to solve this in general.  I remove the tag `django-class-based-views`, since my question is only about python. It is not related to django. I renamed the method to  `do_magic()` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I can see 2 solutions here.

1) [Brute-ish and relatively easy] Find all occurrences of "do_magic" in your code and wrap it with decorator like:

```
def trace_this(fn):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        print("do_magic is called!")
        result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Result is:{0}".format(result))
        return result
return wrapped
...
@trace_this
def do_magic():
    ...
```

2) Run django as:

```
python -m trace -t manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000 --noreload > trace.txt
```

and all invoked code would be in trace.txt that you can then parse/analyze with tools you prefer.

Comment: Solution1: I would need to find all "do_magic" methods first. Hmmm, this is not what I was looking for. Solution2: Yes, this does work. It would be nice if you could trace only methods called "do_magic". But I can use `grep` on the big trace.txt file to do the filtering, too.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding what you want are the outer frames of a particular function call to see what classes were called to lead to the method in question.

### If it is what you want continue below, else let me know in the comments:

Below is an POC to demonstrate how it works. You can build a decorator out of it.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import inspect


class A:
    def a(self):
        stacks = inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())
        for stack in stacks:
            frame = stack[0]
            klass = frame.f_locals.get("self")
            mthd = frame.f_code.co_name
            if klass: # to avoid printing modules
                print('Called by class: {0}, method: {1}'.format(klass.__class__.__name__, mthd))

class B:
    def b(self):
        bb = A()
        bb.a()

class C:
    def c(self):
        cc = B()
        cc.b()

z = C()
z.c()
```

### Output:

[image]

### Explanation:

1. `Class C` calls `Class B` which in turn calls `Class A`
2. When the execution reaches till `A.a()` all the classes that inherited `A` are in the outer frames.
3. You can extract out just the functionality of `A.a()` to carve out a decorator so that it will print all outer frames leading upto the function call.

Comment: Yes, this looks good. I just don't know how to write a decorator, since AFAIK `inspect.getouterframes()` needs to be called in the inner most implementation of `do_magic()`

Comment: If that is the case write a static method and call that method at the final step of `do_magic`. That should be able to solve this. Did this fulfill your requirement?

Comment: I updated the question: I don't want to modify the code to be able to trace it.

Comment: Then unfortunately I am limited by knowledge to answer you this and could be of no help to you. But I have asked around my senior he had suggested some package called [pyflame](https://github.com/uber/pyflame). If you give it a go kindly let me know. Thanks @guettli